# Login Progress Dialog prompting error

Tags: android

i want a progress dialog to show while login in user...
i have have follow different solutions but still show me dis 
error

WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mariamhp.inicrepot.login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1ebb896b V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,322} that was originally added here

```
     bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();


            if(username.length()==0){
                etUsername.requestFocus();
                etUsername.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            }
            else if(!username.matches("[0-1a-zA-Z]+"))
            {
                etUsername.requestFocus();
                etUsername.setError("ENTER ONLY ALPHANUMIRIC CHARACTER");
            }
            else if(password.length()==0)
            {
                etPassword.requestFocus();
                etPassword.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            }else {
                final ProgressDialog progresRing = ProgressDialog.show(login.this, "Login in", "Please Wait...", true);
                progresRing.setCancelable(true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                            progresRing.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }

                // Response received from the server
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, user_area.class);
                                login.this.startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();


                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(login.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);

            }
        }
    );
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (progresRing != null) {
        progresRing.dismiss();
        progresRing = null;
    }
}
```

}

Please any possible solution.... here is my logcat

```
    E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mariamhp.inicrepot.login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1ebb896b V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,322} that was originally added here
                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                 at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
                 at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
                 at com.example.mariamhp.inicrepot.login$2.onClick(login.java:64)
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should dismiss the progress bar before going to next activity.

So before call to next activity dismiss progress bar.

```
 // Here dismiss the progress bar
 Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, user_area.class);
 login.this.startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

Comment: application clash when i add progressRing.dismiss  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please declare ProgressDialog progresRing before onCreate.